# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error. The response had HTTP status code 503

Tags: javascript

I built an api in ExpressJS + MongoDB. When I make a get/post request from Postman, everything works fine but when i request it from my javascript file I get an error : 503 (Service Unavailable) and  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

My javascript file :

```html
function add_score(user,level,score){
  
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "http://tranquil-mountain-64247.herokuapp.com/api/scores";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("sim");
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("user="+user+"&level="+level+"&time="+score);
}
```

My api file:

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://...");

app.get('/api/scores', (req,res) => {
    Score.getScores((err, scores) => {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(scores);
    })

});

app.post('/api/scores', (req, res) => {
 var score = req.body;
 Score.addScore(score, (err, score) => {
  if(err){
   throw err;
  }
  res.json(score);
 });
});
```

Comment: It seems to be a cross origin problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy . It would be useful if you updated your question specifying the browser that you're using to test it (there might be differences between browsers (e.g., chrome or firefox) and versions (e.g., 47 vs 57)). BTW, nice username you got there;) but this might lead you to trouble down the road

Comment: there are two issues - the first issue you need to resolve is why your server is responding with a 503 (which has zero to do with CORS) - and then you need to add the CORS responses

Answer (score 0):

Add CORS headers to your response that is being returned from express/api.

https://enable-cors.org/index.html

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
     Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Comment: How will this fix a 503 response status?

Comment: Server is not responding to requests those are coming from different origin, so adding CORS headers will fix this.

Comment: No, adding response headers in the server code won't fix a service unavailable response - yes, CORS headers will fix the access-control-* error, but not the HTTP response error. I'd say that the 503 reswponse is not coming from the OP's code anyway (it may be a result of his code though), so adding response headers to his code will not result in access-control-* headers being sent in the response, as his code is probably not even issuing the response at this stage